# Configuração de database usando o rspec-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Em meu **spec/rails_helper.rb** adicionei o seguinte código para que a database fosse criada automaticamente ao executar **rspec**:

```
def database_exists?
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection rescue ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError ? false : true
end
unless database_exists?
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:"#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}")
  db_config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[ENV['RAILS_ENV']]
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_database db_config
end
```

mas ao executar **rspec** tenho o seguinte erro:

> .rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:23:in `rescue in mysql2_connection': Unknown database 'my-db-test' (ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError)

Não era para ter criado a database?

Se eu colocar `system('rake db:create')` funciona, mas é uma boa prática fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma rake task para preparar o banco de testes:

`bundle exec rake db:test:prepare`

Este comando cria o banco, roda as migrações e carrega o schema. A partir daí podes rodar a suite de testes.

Comment: Como posso fazer isso automaticamente quando a suite de testes é executada?

Comment: adicionei **system('rake db:test:prepare')** no meu **spec/rails_helper.rb**

Comment: Se vc rodar a suíte de testes com o comando `rake spec` ao invés de diretamente com `rspec` está task também será rodada antes da execução dos testes.